# Generating Function for Bivariate Legendre Polynomials?

Tags: generating-functions, legendre-polynomials

I am aware of the following standard generating function for single-variable Legendre Polynomials:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)z^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xz+z^2}}
$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{C}$, with $|{z}| < 1$.

Is there any known generating function for the bivariate Legendre Polynomials?

For context, Sehili and Zerroug (2017) give the following Rodrigues formula:
$$
P_{i,j}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2^{i+j}i!j!}\frac{\partial^i}{\partial x^i}(x^2 - 1)^i\frac{\partial^j}{\partial y^j}(y^2-1)^j
$$ and a recurrence relation for the bivariate case I'm working with:
$$
\begin{cases} 
P_{-1,j}(x,y) = 0\\
P_{i,-1}(x,y) = 0\\
P_{0,0}(x,y) = 1\\
P_{0,0}(x,y) = 1\\
P_{i+1,j}(x,y) = \frac{2i+1}{i+1}xP_{i,j}(x,y) - \frac{i}{i+1}P_{i-1,j}(x,y)\\
P_{i,j+1}(x,y) = \frac{2j+1}{j+1}yP_{i,j}(x,y) - \frac{j}{j+1}P_{i,j-1}(x,y)\\
\end{cases}
$$
The paper can be found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjf79nDtMGCAxWyD1kFHURQA70QFnoECC4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencepubco.com%2Findex.php%2Fijamr%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F8198%2F2904&usg=AOvVaw2xJiTFLuKUxbKJntkDSFSM&opi=89978449).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper uses power $j$ instead of $2$ in $(y^2-1)$.

But with this definition, doesn't it just hold that $P_{i,j}(x,y) = P_i(x) P_j(y)$?

If I'm not missing something and it's true, you can just do
$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty P_{i,j}(x,y) a^i b^j = \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty P_i(x) a^i\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty P_j(y) b^j\right).
$$
This, in turn, gives the generating function
$$
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xa+a^2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2yb+b^2}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that crucial typo. 
I didn't notice that! It looks like that's the case, although I haven't sat down to prove it or anything yet.